# Implementing ISupportIncrementalLoading in WPF and WP8

Tags: wpf, listview, winrt-xaml, virtualization

WinRT applications have a simple way to add virtualization to ListView control. If a collection implements ISupportIncrementalLoading, it can be used for partial async loading of large number of items.

I am trying to solve this task on other platforms: WPF and WP8. This interface is not available there but I wonder if there is an implementation that matches closely WinRT counterpart.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Might be helpful :

[data virtualization or the lazy loading of data to a ListView](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/1b2f6efe-3041-4e62-914b-9023585abfc9/)

[Data virtualization](http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/498#)